# When simply `| cat -`, I get file descriptor errors

Tags: zsh, pipe, io-redirection, command-substitution, file-descriptors

Here's the working diff command:

```bash
$ diff -u <(echo 'foo:bar:baz' | tr : "\n") <(echo 'foo:baz' | tr : "\n")
--- /dev/fd/11  2023-08-30 13:11:50
+++ /dev/fd/13  2023-08-30 13:11:50
@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
 foo
-bar
 baz
```

Anything that I add a pipe from `diff`, every command fails with this error:

```bash
$ diff -u <(echo 'foo:bar:baz' | tr : "\n") <(echo 'foo:baz' | tr : "\n") | command cat -
diff: /dev/fd/11: Bad file descriptor
```

Using `command cat -` instead of `cat -` in case of shell plugins doing "magic".

Can anyone explain *why* and what I should do to work around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in zsh 5.9 (with default shell options set).

Comment: I can't reproduce in bash on 22.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: possibly diff is an alias?  try `command diff`

Comment: Does it also happen if you replace `diff -u` with another command such as `cat`?

Comment: Does it also happen within `zsh -f` or in `zsh -c 'diff -u <(echo 'foo:bar:baz' | tr : "\n") <(echo 'foo:baz' | tr : "\n") |  cat'`

Comment: What's your version of `zsh`?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `diff` is a function I'd defined locally to ensure colorized diffs. I still can't explain why that would cause issues. However, my fix was to simply use `command diff` instead of `diff`.

Comment: It would have been interesting to see that function definition in the question, to be able to say in exactly what way it fails, and possibly give hints about how to fix it.

Comment: I can reproduce in 5.8.1 with `f() { cat "$@"; }; f <(echo x) | cat`. Looks like a bug in zsh. Can be worked around with `{ f <(echo x); } | cat`. Looks like it was fixed in 5.9